# Mulesoft HTTP Connector configuration

Tags: mule, mule-studio

When I connect to:

```
http://legacy.cafebonappetit.com/api/2/menus?cafe=261
```

I get back JSON as I should. However, I'm unable to do this with the Mulesoft HTTP Connector. When I try, I get back 500.  Here is my XML:

```
    <flow name="GetDiningInfo">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/dining" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/api/2/menus" method="GET" doc:name="GET announcement from dining server" followRedirects="true" host="legacy.cafebonappetit.com" port="80">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:query-param paramName="cafe" value="261"/>
        </http:request-builder>
    </http:request>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

The connector global config is:

```
    <http:request-config name="HTTPReqConfigforCafeBonAppetit.com" host="legacy.cafebonappetit.com" port="80" basePath="/api/2" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks...

UPDATE: Still no joy. I'm still getting back a 500 internal server failure through Mule.

Here is the latest code that does not duplicate the path:

```
<http:request-config name="HTTPReqConfigforCafeBonAppetit" host="legacy.cafebonappetit.com" port="80" basePath="/api/2/" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" usePersistentConnections="false"/>

<flow name="GetDiningInfo">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/dining" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <http:request config-ref="HTTPReqConfigforCafeBonAppetit" path="menus" method="GET" doc:name="GET menu" followRedirects="true" parseResponse="false">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:query-param paramName="cafe" value="261"/>
        </http:request-builder>
    </http:request>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: Can you share the Request_config as well?

Comment: @afelisatti Added to the original question, thanks!

Comment: When do you get the below error .  Am close to solution I think .
<h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
            <p>Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.</p>
            <p>Filename: /var/www/vhosts/cafebonappetit.com/httpdocs/legacy/core/MY_Loader.php</p>
            <p>Line Number: 33</p>

Comment: The config makes the error apparent. As it was answered, you are defining a base path (/api/v2) and then a path that already includes that (api/v2/menus). You should use "menus" as path.

Comment: @afelisatti Can you provide the code that gets the error ? I tried and was getting the error. If you can provide the code i will remove my answer or edit my answer. I have already tried with the Requestor but it did not work and I was not able to find the reason. Can you help in this ? That is the reason I used the deprecated HTTP connector. Yes the the path is double but I considered that he might have tried many methodologies and then landed on something and he had provided the code that he had. I may be wrong.

Comment: ```<http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="menus" method="GET" doc:name="GET announcement from dining server" followRedirects="true">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:query-param paramName="cafe" value="261"/>
        </http:request-builder>
    </http:request>```

Comment: @afelisatti If I was constructing the path incorrectly wouldn't that typically result in a 404 error, for not found? At the bottom of my question I posted the latest code I tried and it still generates a 505. I don't think I'm duplicating the /api/2 in this one. Is there a way to see the URI that Mule is constructing?

Comment: I took a closer look and it seems your server rejects request where the host includes the port. Mule sends ```Host: legacy.cafebonappetit.com:80``` by default, so to get it to work you need to explicitly add the header. I'll answer with a full example below.

Comment: Great thank you!  But I was able to make this work with Postman:  legacy.cafebonappetit.com:80/api/2/menus?cafe=261

Comment: @afelisatti I hope you get to know why I provided the code that works using the outbound endpoint. It is because of the issue which you provided a solution. The one I provided could also be a solution to the same as well.

Comment: Yes, it's a valid workaround but it's using a deprecated component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server for `legacy.cafebonappetit.com` cannot handle the header Host including the port (which is [valid](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.23)). The HTTP connector sends `Host: legacy.cafebonappetit.com:80` by default causing the server to reject the request, so you need to explicitly add the Host header, as in the example below.

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="legacy.cafebonappetit.com" port="80" basePath="/api/2" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
<flow name="so-testFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/dining" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="menus" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:query-param paramName="cafe" value="261"/>
            <http:header headerName="Host" value="legacy.cafebonappetit.com"/>
        </http:request-builder>
        <http:success-status-code-validator values="100..599"/>
    </http:request>
</flow>
```

The example also includes a status code validator for all codes which allows you to see the exact error the server sends when the explicit Host header is removed.

Comment: Thanks! Thats working. But, if I use Postman to hit this server and I do include the port in the URL, it works fine. Any idea why?

Comment: Well I'm using Wireshark (https://www.wireshark.org/) to see the actual request Postman sends and the Host header does not include the port (even when adding it explicitly) so I'm guessing the port is being removed, probably because it seems many servers fail to handle it.

Comment: While using postman or directly Calling the service you don't mention the portname in them at all. Is there a reason why the server might reject the port ??

Comment: Some servers are just not coded right :) They might be using the Host header value to calculate something without considering that the port might be there.

Answer (score 2):

Have you evaluated the URL request result? By referring that configuration it should be http://legacy.cafebonappetit.com/api/2/api/2/menus?cafe=261

That's why you unable to get the expected result. Therefore replace the *path* of *http:request* with `/menus`, without the base path */api/2*. Because it's already defined in *http:request-config*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'l still struggling with this. I did as you suggest and I'm now getting 404. Is there a way for me to see what URI Mulesoft is creating from my code?

Answer (score 0):

Well the trouble here is when you send a request to the server by the 80 port. The server rejects the request immediately. To resolve this you got to add the header, so this way the server understand and process the request.

To do that just add the following line:                                      `$<http:header headerName="Host" value="the_host"/>`.

The following XML got the solution:

```
<http:listener-config name="localhost" port="8085" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" host="0.0.0.0"/>
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="legacy.cafebonappetit.com" port="80"  doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" basePath="/api/2"/>
<flow name="GetDiningInfo">
    <http:listener config-ref="localhost" path="/dining" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/menus" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:query-param paramName="cafe" value="261"/>
            <http:header headerName="Host" value="legacy.cafebonappetit.com"/>
        </http:request-builder>
        <http:success-status-code-validator values="100..599"/>
    </http:request>    
     <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[payload]"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to resolve this issue is to make the server process the  request. 
Add this line in the xml,

```
<http:header headerName="Host" value="the_host"/>
```

Comment: $<http:header headerName="Host" value="the_host"/>

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete base path from global configuration of  delete path in your xml because it generates url like : http://legacy.cafebonappetit.com/api/2/api/2/menus?cafe=261

here in url api/2/api/2 generated twice so thats why error occured

Answer (score 0):

The server for legacy.cafebonappetit.com cannot handle the header Host including the port (which is valid). 
The HTTP connector sends Host: legacy.cafebonappetit.com:80 by default causing the server to reject the request, so you need to explicitly add the Host header, as in the example below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5luF.png)

Comment: Welcome KranthiKumar! Could you please add your example to the answer highlighting the important lines? We try to make our answers last — one can never be sure the link will be valid in a couple of years.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the code like this

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" 
port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" 
host="legacy.cafebonappetit.com" port="80" basePath="/api/2" doc:name="HTTP 
Request Configuration"/>
<flow name="so-testFlow">
<http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/dining" 
doc:name="HTTP"/>
<http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="menus" 
method="GET" doc:name="HTTP">
<http:request-builder>
        <http:query-param paramName="cafe" value="261"/>
        <http:header headerName="Host" value="legacy.cafebonappetit.com"/>
    </http:request-builder>
    <http:success-status-code-validator values="100..599"/>
</http:request>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code for your issue...

```
<http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/menus" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP">
    <http:request-builder>
        <http:query-param paramName="cafe" value="261"/>
        <http:header headerName="Host" value="the_host"/>
    </http:request-builder>
    <http:success-status-code-validator values="100..599"/>
</http:request>
```

Answer (score 0):

http:request-builder

try to add a header

Answer (score -1):

The below code seems to work.

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8084" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>

<http:endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" name="HTTP" address="http://legacy.cafebonappetit.com/api/2/menus?cafe=261" doc:name="HTTP"/>
<flow name="GetDiningInfo">
<http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/dining" doc:name="HTTP"/>
 <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```